# Can I create my own properties in styles?

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to create my own properly in a style, is it possible?

I have the foliwing style

```
<Style x:Key="EditTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
</Style>
```

and I want to add a property that is called 'OPERATION'...

Anybody know if that is possible?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to do that. But you could use other existing properties like `Tag` or `DataContext`.

Comment: Thank  Benoit Blanchon

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon You can do that with an Attached property

Comment: @loetn: Right ! But you can't create your own attached property "on the fly". You need to define them in code.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon Indeed, but I didn't read his question like that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add another property to a 'TextBox' you need to extend the class, for example:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OperationProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Operation", //property name
            typeof(string), //property type
            typeof(CustomTextBox), //owner type
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Default value")
        );
    public string Operation
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(OperationProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OperationProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can set your custom textbox style:

```
<Style x:Key="EditTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type CustomTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Operation" Value="string value"/>
</Style>
```

Or

```
<my:CustomTextBox Operation="My value" Text="You can still use it as a textbox" />
```

The DependencyProperty is so you can edit it from XAML and the object property is so you can access it from C#.